# How to allow additions but disable edits in an Access form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to set up a form so that users:

- Can view/sort/filter all existing table records
- Can add new records
- **Cannot** edit or delete records once they have been added

I tried the following property settings:

- Allow Additions="Yes"
- Allow Deletions="No"
- Allow Edits="No"

With these settings, edits and deletions are disabled, but it's not possible to add new records; there's no asterisk row at the bottom of the table for adding new records, and the navigation controls at the bottom of the screen have the "Add new row" icon grayed out.

When I set Allow Edits back to "Yes", I get the new row re-enabled, but I also get the ability to edit existing rows, which I don't want.  How can I allow adds but prevent edits?

EDIT: I originally built this form by creating a blank form, then dragging the table onto the form.  When I built it differently, by opening the table and then clicking the Create Form button, I was able to set it to allow additions, but not deletions or edits, using the above property settings.  Seems like this is an issue with the way the form is set up when created using drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no MS Access on the computer at the moment, but you can open new form from vba using [`DoCmd.OpenForm()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx). With the `DataMode` argument can set `acFormAdd` which will do what you need. For more information [check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191834.aspx).

Comment: I'm not trying to add a form; I want to modify the properties on an existing form.

Comment: If you open the form with this command it will have the properties to add only. It opens an existing form.